# Get single values from ViewBag SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, selectlist, selectlistitem

This question should be rather simple.

I have the following code:

```
            ViewBag.SenderID = new SelectList(db.Senders, "SenderID", "SenderContactName", survey.SenderID);

            //Attempts
            string _SenderContactName = ViewBag.SenderID.ToString();
            string _senderContactName = survey.SenderID.ToString();
```

Results:

`_SenderContactname` = `System.Web.MVC.SelectList`

`_senderContactName` = `"1"`

What I want the result to be is the `SenderContactName` from the VewBag, in the form of a string.
I Believe my second attempt is closer to the working code. But I can´t seem to figure out how to fix it on my own.

Comment: You are storing a SelectList object into the SenderId property of the ViewBag.  If you attempt to call ToString on that property you will get back the type as you describe.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you should do:

```
string _senderContactName = db.Senders
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.SenderID == survey.SenderID)
                            .SenderContactName;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will mark as correct answer asap.